# SWIFT Unable to get the total for Dynamic View on button Click

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic

SWIFT Unable to get the total for Dynamic View on button Click.

when i Enter data in one Custom-Dynamic view (TextField) and in the other Cust-Dynamic view (TextField) entered Data.

I want the Total Sum of these two Txt Field in The TextField Outside.

Can Someone Please help me with this Code, [image]

if you Could see at the bottom Overall Sqft has the total Sum Text Field, and number of Cust-Dynamic View are called Sum of all Text Fields result needs to be updated in Overall sqft TextField. 
**eg : 99+99=198.00**
**Thanks in Advance.**

```
    func viewcall()
    {
      //  for _ in 0..<count {
        myView = customSubView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 220+y_value, width: 400, height: 245))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
        myView.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        myView.Board_height.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didChangeText(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        myView.actionButton.addTarget(self, action: (#selector(cancelbutton(_:))), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        myView.NoofBoardtext.addTarget(self, action:#selector(didChangeTexts(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        myView.numberofdays.addTarget(self, action:#selector(dayscalculation(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        self.scrlview.addSubview(myView)

}
func didChangeText(textField: UITextField)
    {
        myView.Board_total.text = String(Int(myView.Board_size.text!)! * Int(myView.Board_height.text!)!)

    }
//only Calculation for total SQFT
    func didChangeTexts(textField: UITextField)
    {
        myView.totalSQFT.text = String(Int(myView.NoofBoardtext.text!)! * Int(myView.Board_total.text!)!)
    }
//only Calculation for total SQFT
    func dayscalculation(textField: UITextField)
    {
       myView.totalDays.text = myView.numberofdays.text!
       myView.Totalsqfttext.text = String(Int(myView.totalSQFT.text!)! * Int(myView.numberofdays.text!)!)
        overallSQFTtext.text = myView.Totalsqfttext.text
    }
```